# Xcode build step to verify if Cocoapods are up to date

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have an iOS project that is already set up with Cocoapods. I use a bunch of libraries, but sometimes I add/remove/update libraries between different branches and forget to run `pod update` in the terminal to make sure I have all the correct pods for the branch I'm working on.

What I'm trying to set up a build step in my project (iOS 7, Xcode 5) that performs the following actions:

1. Check if the Pods are currently up to date, i.e. determine the need to run `pod update`.
2. If the Pods are up to date, do nothing.
3. If the Pods are NOT up to date, run `pod update`/`pod install`

I'm looked through the documentation in the [Cocoapods](http://docs.cocoapods.org/) website and couldn't find the solution to my problem.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Cheers,
Mário

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of Xcode plugins that make things easier but I don't think they will do auto updating:

Handy Xcode Plugin For Working With CocoaPods: [ManiacDev](http://maniacdev.com/2013/07/handy-xcode-plugin-for-working-with-cocoapods)
An Xcode 5 Plugin For Easier Cocoapods Usage And Podfile Creation: [ManiacDev](http://maniacdev.com/2013/09/an-xcode-5-plugin-for-easier-cocoapods-usage-and-podfile-creation)

CocoaPods for Xcode: [kattrali/cocoapods-xcode-plugin](https://github.com/kattrali/cocoapods-xcode-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

> Based on [weissazool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20536771/4488252) answer

### Details

- Xcode 10
- Cocoapods 1.6.1 beta

### Solution 1. Check without caching

```
no_updates="No pod updates are available."
need_to_update=1
pod outdated | (while read i
    do
        if [ "$i" == "$no_updates" ]; then
        need_to_update=0   
    fi
done
    if [ $need_to_update == 1 ]; then
        echo "warning: need to update pods";
    fi
)
```

### Solution 2. Check only 1 time per day

```
DIR="Temp"
FILE="./$DIR/Pods.check"

CURRENT_DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`

checkPods () {
    NEED_TO_UPDATE_PODS=1
    NO_PODS_UPDATE_STRING="No pod updates are available."
    > $FILE
    pod outdated | (while read LINE
    do
        if [ "$LINE" = "$NO_PODS_UPDATE_STRING" ]
        then
            NEED_TO_UPDATE_PODS=0
        fi
    done
        echo "$CURRENT_DATE" >> $FILE
        if [ $NEED_TO_UPDATE_PODS = 1 ]
        then
            str="warning: need to update pods"
            echo "$str"
            echo "$str" >> $FILE
        fi
    )
}

mkdir -p $DIR

if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]
then
    checkPods
else
    INDEX='0'
    cat $FILE | while read LINE
    do

    if [ $INDEX = 0 ] && [ $CURRENT_DATE != $LINE ]
    then
        checkPods
        break
    fi

    if [ $INDEX = 1 ]
    then
        echo "$LINE"
        break
    fi

    INDEX=`expr $INDEX + 1`
    done
fi
```

### Results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, edit your build scheme - `cmd-option-r`

Build -> Pre-actions

Add a `New Run Script Action`

I came up with this script that works for me - but my bash-fu is lacking so others may have more elegant solutions.

```
pod outdated | while read i
do
flag=`echo $i | awk '{print match($0,"No updates")}'`;
if [ $flag -gt 0 ]; then
    break;
else
    pod update;
    break;      
fi
done
```

Note also that this relies on `pod outdated`'s text output not changing, so it's potentially fragile as Cocoapods gets updated.